# Script running fine locally but throwing error while running on server

Tags: powershell

Sorry but I checked all the other post similar to this, but could not find the working solution.

error:-
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.

I want to delete files older than 30 days from folder and sub folder.
Script running fine locally but throwing error while running on server.
powershell version is 5.
Any help is appreciated!
script:-

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "D:\file\source" –Include *.* -File -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Your server likely has a very old PowerShell version where `-File` didn't yet existed. You can add `-not $_.PSIsContainer` to your filtering

Comment: To add to Santiago's comment:`-File` was introduced in v3 of PowerShell. Execute `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` in the remote script block to determine the server's version.

Comment: By the way, probably unrelated but, the code you're showing us has an en-dash `–` in the `Path` and `Include` parameters, this can potentially bring encoding issues

Comment: If the code is valid when ran local, and the remote PowerShell version is reasonably recent, then the only question I can think to ask is: How are you running it on the remote server?  Are you copying the script to the server and remotely executing it there?  Running the code in a scriptblock that is ran remotely on the server?  PS remoting? Remote desktop connection and running from there?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

If your server is running a PowerShell version greater than or equal to 3.0 - which you report to be the case (v5.1) -  **the implication is that *your server has no `D:` drive*** or, at least hypothetically, that `D:` is not a *file-system* drive, but backed by a *different* PowerShell [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers).

The resulting error message, `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'`, is unfortunate in that it misleadingly suggests a *syntax* error, which isn't the case here.

---

While it is true that the `-File` switch parameter (along with `-Directory`) wasn't available until version *3* of PowerShell, the error message you saw - `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'` - can *situationally* also occur in later versions, because it is a so-called *dynamic* parameter that is specific to the PowerShell's `FileSystem` provider.

That is, the `-File` parameter is *not* available if you combine it with:

- a path based on a drive whose provider is a provider *other* than the `FileSystem` provider (with *relative* paths, the drive is *implied* by the current location)
- a path referencing a drive *that doesn't exist*.

The resulting error message (quoted above) does *not* distinguish between those two cases (and *cannot*, because a non-existent drive cannot be assumed to be a *file-system* drive in PowerShell).

An easy way to provoke the error is with the following command: 
`Get-ChildItem variable:* -File`

Arguably, a better error message would be something along the lines of: `-File is only applicable to file-system paths`.
However, given the open-ended nature of PowerShell's provider architecture:

- A complete, but expensive solution would require knowing the dynamic, provider-specific parameters across *all* providers, and reporting any unknown parameter that happens to be a different provider's dynamic parameter as such.
- Conceivably, to lessen the cost, hard-coded errors for `-File` and `-Directory` only could be implemented, given that file-system provider operations are by far the most common ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a delete function that I use.  I confirmed that it will run on the 5.1 Powershell you are using:

```
function DeleteOldFiles {
    param (
        [string]$file
    )
    Remove-Item -Path $file
}

Set-Location 'D:\file\source'
    
    $fileList = Get-ChildItem -Depth 1 | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}

    foreach($f in $fileList)
    {
        DeleteOldFiles -file $f.FullName
    }
```

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  5127

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the feedback.  Updated the answer to reflect the OP specific file path; changed the directory depth to 1 as the OP indicated a single subfolder; and removed the specifications around file type.  I did add a check so that any folders would not be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Note that `-Depth 1` goes _two_ levels deep; simply don't use `-Depth` in order to examine just the immediate child items. Also note that it's better not to use `Set-Location` in scripts / functions, because it affects the _entire session_.

Comment: As for  using `$_.PSIsContainer` to determine if an item is a file instead of using `-File`: I may have led you down the wrong path, my apologies: while either approach works, `-File` is much simpler and preferable in v3+, and John may indeed be on v5.1, as he states, given that the error message cited in the question can also occur in v3+ versions, namely if the targeted drive (`D:`) doesn't exist or isn't backed by PowerShell's _file-system_ provider.